# Dynamically generated image is bigger than original image in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, resize

In my asp.net mvc application I am uploading image and resizing same to 800x600 pixel size, converting it to PNG format and then saving it to disk. I am using following code

```
public void ResizeImg(HttpPostedFileBase UploadImg)
{
    if (UploadImg != null)
    {
       Stream s = UploadImg.InputStream;
       Image UploadedImg = Image.FromStream(s);
       int Width = UploadedImg.Width;
       int Height = UploadedImg.Height;

    int ResizeWidth = 800, ResizeHeight = 600;

    using (var newImage = new Bitmap(ResizeWidth, ResizeHeight))
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        /* Resizing */
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Default;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Default;
        graphics.DrawImage(UploadedImg, new Rectangle(0, 0, ResizeWidth, ResizeHeight));
        newImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

        /* Saving resized image */
        FileStream fileStream = File.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/GeneratedBarcode/testing.png"), (int)stream.Length);

        byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);

        fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);           
    }
}
```

}

code is working properly. But issue is that original image is 1024x768 jpg image which is 858 KB and after resize it is 800x600 png image with 1.16MB
Why after resizing to smaller size and converting to png image size become larger than origianl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for that issue. Instead of saving image in PNG formate, I am saving it in JPEG formate like this:

```
 //newImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
 newImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I don't know why but it works for me.